# Why am I not getting a compile error when passing a list of Integer for a list of String parameter?

Tags: java, openjdk-12

```java
public class Generic<T> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Generic g = new Generic();
        List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<>();
        integerList.add(42);
        g.f(integerList);
        System.out.println(integerList);
    }

    void f(List<String> stringList){
        stringList.add("hello");
    }
}
```

Executing this code will COMPILE and print `[42, hello]`

I'm passing my `List<Integer> integerList` to a `List<String> stringList` and the compiler is fine with it. Why? Isn't the compiler suppose to check this sort of things? Line with `g.f(integerList);` should throw a compile error. It's not.

Comment: The compiler is indeed raising errors for this code. Can't reproduce your outcome.

Comment: For me it compiles with warnings. You should probably check the warnings.

Comment: Interesting that the compiler errors if the `<T>` type is removed, even though it is not used. And it errors if you specify a type for your generic instance `g`. But when you use a raw version of the generic type `Generic`, it seems to forget to do type checking on `f`, even though the type `T` is irrelevant to that. Weird quirk.

Comment: What IDE do you use? What is java -version?
I tried with 8 and 11 and both produce "Note: Generic.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations." warning, but produce .class though

Comment: `class Generic<T> {` should be `class Generic {`. Now you create an unsafe `Generic g` and the compiler no longer checks for generic typing: for backward compatibility.

Comment: Latest IntelliJ + OpenJDK12 from Zulu